# make_pair does not work with string, works with string&

Tags: c++, c++11

```
counts[k] = make_pair<string, int>(s, count_inversion(pos, 0, pos.size()));
```

Whenever `make_pair` is used like `make_pair<string,int>(s,i)` it gives an error:

```
error: no matching function to call for 'make_pair(std::__cxx11::string&, int)'
note: cannot convert 's' (type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}') to type 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&&'
```

However `make_pair<string&,int>(s,i)` works fine. Can somebody explain this. If the variable `s` is changed after `make_pair` call in the latter case, will it affect the pair?

Comment: 1. Don't post images of code. 2. See point 1. 3. You seem to be missing some backticks (inline code formatting) in the question's body, and angle bracktes are eaten as a result. Have you looked at the question preview before posting?

Comment: I fixed the question for you this time, because I consider it interesting and wouldn't want it to get closed for bad formatting, but *please* format it properly next time.

Comment: Thank you @Angrew. Will make sure to put questions in proper format from next time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::make_pair` is intended to be used *without* explicitly specifying template arguments. And since C++11, it uses perfect forwarding, which makes it very hard (and *even more pointless*) to supply template arguments manually.

Use `std::make_pair` when you want to deduce the types in the pair from the types of the arguments to `make_pair`.

Use `std::pair<T, U>` when you want explicit control of the types in the pair.

Notice that in your case, calling `make_pair(s, count_inversion(pos, 0, pos.size()))` will actually deduce the templte parameters to `string&` and `whatever the return type of count_inversion is`. This doesn't mean the pair will contain a reference, it's just perfect forwarding in action. So the produced pair will contain a copy of `s` and will not be affected by future changes to `s`.

Using `std::pair<string&, int>` would be different and would indeed give you a live reference to `s` in the pair.